# NoClassDefFoundError in simple .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to create a simple .jar file out of my project. The project is made of two .class files - the main class which uses the secondary class to generate a GUI. The main class is the actual "main" class that runs while the second class is just a class file with it's methods and it's also an *extension* of JFrame and imports javax.swing and java.awt.event.*.

I use Jar to bundle it all up. I add a manifest file (with a new line character) which points to the primary file with the main method. The Jar file thus has two .class files and a folder with the manifest.txt in it. When I use javaw.exe to run it, nothing happens at all. So I try to run it in the command line and I get a NoClassDefFroundError about the secondary class.

I noticed I get the same kind of error when I try to compile and run the second class in JCreator - no wonder, it doesn't have a main method, it's just a class file. When I run the main file from JCreator, everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second class (without the main method) is using JFrame.

Comment: If your classes are defined to belong to a package, perhaps there aren't entries in the jar file for the corresponding directories?

Comment: Please show us the results of running `jar tvf foo.jar` along with the exact error message.

Comment: The stacktrace is important as Jon Skeet notes.  A NoDefClassFoundError doesn't necessarily mean the app is throwing a ClassNotFoundException, it is possible there was a failure when initializing a class.

Comment: @Protagonist what does the stacktrace look like? If you copy and paste the stacktrace into your question that would help.

Comment: @Jon The results are:          0 Tue Sep 06 12:07:36 EDT 2011 META-INF/
    95 Tue Sep 06 12:07:36 EDT 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  1689 Tue Sep 06 11:43:20 EDT 2011 grafPrime.class
   438 Tue Sep 06 11:43:26 EDT 2011 ShowWindow.class<br/> and <br/><br/>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grafPrime$calcButton
        at grafPrime.<init>(grafPrime.java:22)
        at ShowWindow.main(ShowWindow.java:7)

Comment: Cont: <br>Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grafPrime$calcButton
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 2 more

Comment: @Ernest This may as well be a problem. I'll admit that I just started out with Java and I have no concept of packages. @ John V. What is a stacktrace? Maybe I took a bigger bite than I could handle for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace, I can now see the problem: I can tell you actually have more than two classes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grafPrime$calcButton at
```

There's a file named `grafPrime$calcButton.class`, and it needs to be in the jar file, too. There may be other such files -- make sure you include all of them!

Comment: Yep, that was it. How stupid of me, but at least I got it working alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the problem is that you've not included the anonymous class - you should have a file called `grafPrime$calcButton.class`, and that's not in your jar file.

Basically, compile your code into a clean directory and include *all* the class files which are generated.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. I'd like to thank all of you guys because You helped me track the correct solution. The problem was that I was missing the grafPrime$calcButton.class and a few other class files. I fixed it by recompiling the secondary class file that then created like 3-4 actual class files. Again, thanks so much!